Does a positive row-space kernel imply a positive column-space kernel for a square matrix?
Let $A$ be a square matrix: in my setting, $A = I-DG$, where $I$ is the identity, $D$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries, and $G$ is a symmetric matrix with non-negative entries. Now suppose that there exists a vector $v$ with all positive entries so that $v^T A = 0$. Does this imply that there exists a vector $w$ with all positive entries so that $Aw = 0$? I'm pretty sure that this should be true, but I can't quite figure out how to prove it. I was looking into the Perron-Frobenius theorem, but didn't find anything that was immediately helpful.
Thanks a lot!

why don't you start by considering the similar $I-GD$ and then work backwards.

ahh, I got it, thanks!

I figured it out! Actually is quite simple. Consider
$$(I-DG)v=0 \Rightarrow D(D^{-1} - G)v = 0 \Rightarrow D(I - GD) D^{-1} v=0 \Rightarrow (I - GD)D^{-1} v=0. $$
Here, the third implication is true because $D$ is of full rank, and $D^{-1} v$ has all positive entries since $D$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries. Thanks to the commenter for the suggestion :)
